# Easiest way to get all static properties of a Class in php

Tags: php, class

I have a static class Foo (this isn't a real class, so static fields are just for example)

```
class Foo{
    public static $name = "foo";
    public static $age = "18";
    public static $city = "Boston";
}
```

In my code I want to build an array of all the public static properties and their current values.

Is there a quick/easy way anyone can suggest to do this without instantiating a Foo?

Comment: Can you write a static Method to return your static properties as an array?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use a `ReflectionClass` instance like this to get an array of the property names and values:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('Foo');
$staticProperties = $class->getStaticProperties();

foreach ($staticProperties as $propertyName => $value) { 
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: Actually, the resulting $class is a ReflectionClass object not a Foo, which is fine--I'm not saying no objects, just no Foo's.  The Foo constructor is never called--which is why I didnt' want to instatiate the Foo.  This meets my needs exactly.

Answer (score 8):

Use the Reflection

```
<?php
require_once "Foo.php";
$reflection = new ReflectionClass("Foo"); 
$staticProperties = $reflection->getStaticProperties();
print_r($staticProperties)
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticproperties.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getstaticpropertyvalue.php

Comment: @roychri I'm sure I could learn the ins-and-outs of PHP reflection and it might solve my issue, but I was hoping to avoid a long learning curve for solving small issue.

Comment: I think for 99.99% of questions we could always technically say RTFM.  You have a design problem, well, read 10 books on design patterns.  Problem with your kernel module, well, the linux kernel source code is open, so read through it.  Heck, why have stack overflow at all.

Comment: I just noticed you edited your answer with an example of using reflection.  Here's +10 from ancient history.